# UnstructuredURLLoader not able to see libmagic

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I tried to use `UnstructuredURLLoader` as below

```
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredURLLoader

loaders = UnstructuredURLLoader(urls=urls)
data = loaders.load()
```

but some pages report that

```
libmagic is unavailable but assists in filetype detection on file-like objects. Please consider installing libmagic for better results.
Error fetching or processing https://wellfound.com/company/chorus-one, exception: Invalid file. The FileType.UNK file type is not supported in partition.
```

while in my conda env I seem to have it

```
%pip list | grep libmagic
libmagic                      1.0
```

but I do not have the `python-libmagic`. When I try to install it:

`pip install python-libmagic`

I keep getting error:

````
Collecting python-libmagic
  Using cached python_libmagic-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi==1.7.0 (from python-libmagic)
  Using cached cffi-1.7.0.tar.gz (400 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi==1.7.0->python-libmagic) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
  Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [254 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/c
      gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/c/_cffi_backend.o
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:274:
      c/minibuffer.h: In function ‘mb_ass_slice’:
      c/minibuffer.h:66:5: warning: ‘PyObject_AsReadBuffer’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         66 |     if (PyObject_AsReadBuffer(other, &buffer, &buffer_len) < 0)
            |     ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/genobject.h:12,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:110,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/abstract.h:343:17: note: declared here
        343 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyObject_AsReadBuffer(PyObject *obj,
            |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:277:
      c/file_emulator.h: In function ‘PyFile_AsFile’:
      c/file_emulator.h:54:14: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
         54 |         mode = PyText_AsUTF8(ob_mode);
            |              ^
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h: In function ‘_my_PyUnicode_AsSingleWideChar’:
      c/wchar_helper.h:83:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         83 |     Py_UNICODE *u = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(unicode);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h:84:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         84 |     if (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode) == 1) {
            |     ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h:84:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         84 |     if (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode) == 1) {
            |     ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h:84:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         84 |     if (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode) == 1) {
            |     ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h: In function ‘_my_PyUnicode_SizeAsWideChar’:
      c/wchar_helper.h:99:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         99 |     Py_ssize_t length = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h:99:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         99 |     Py_ssize_t length = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h:99:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         99 |     Py_ssize_t length = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(unicode);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:281:
      c/wchar_helper.h: In function ‘_my_PyUnicode_AsWideChar’:
      c/wchar_helper.h:118:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        118 |     Py_UNICODE *u = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(unicode);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘ctypedescr_dealloc’:
      c/_cffi_backend.c:352:23: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        352 |         Py_REFCNT(ct) = 43;
            |                       ^
      c/_cffi_backend.c:355:23: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        355 |         Py_REFCNT(ct) = 0;
            |                       ^
      c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘cast_to_integer_or_char’:
      c/_cffi_backend.c:3331:26: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       3331 |                          PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(ob), ct->ct_name);
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:3331:26: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       3331 |                          PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(ob), ct->ct_name);
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:3331:26: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       3331 |                          PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(ob), ct->ct_name);
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘b_complete_struct_or_union’:
      c/_cffi_backend.c:4251:17: warning: ‘PyUnicode_GetSize’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       4251 |                 do_align = PyText_GetSize(fname) > 0;
            |                 ^~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:177:43: note: declared here
        177 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) PyUnicode_GetSize(
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:4283:13: warning: ‘PyUnicode_GetSize’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       4283 |             if (PyText_GetSize(fname) == 0 &&
            |             ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:177:43: note: declared here
        177 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) PyUnicode_GetSize(
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:4353:17: warning: ‘PyUnicode_GetSize’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       4353 |                 if (PyText_GetSize(fname) > 0) {
            |                 ^~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:177:43: note: declared here
        177 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) PyUnicode_GetSize(
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘prepare_callback_info_tuple’:
      c/_cffi_backend.c:5214:5: warning: ‘PyEval_InitThreads’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       5214 |     PyEval_InitThreads();
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/ceval.h:122:37: note: declared here
        122 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘b_callback’:
      c/_cffi_backend.c:5255:5: warning: ‘ffi_prep_closure’ is deprecated: use ffi_prep_closure_loc instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       5255 |     if (ffi_prep_closure(closure, &cif_descr->cif,
            |     ^~
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:15:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/ffi.h:347:1: note: declared here
        347 | ffi_prep_closure (ffi_closure*,
            | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      c/ffi_obj.c: In function ‘_ffi_type’:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:744:29: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        744 | #define _PyUnicode_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
            |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:72:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyUnicode_AsString’
         72 | # define PyText_AS_UTF8 _PyUnicode_AsString
            |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/ffi_obj.c:191:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyText_AS_UTF8’
        191 |             char *input_text = PyText_AS_UTF8(arg);
            |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/lib_obj.c: In function ‘lib_build_cpython_func’:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:744:29: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        744 | #define _PyUnicode_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
            |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:72:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyUnicode_AsString’
         72 | # define PyText_AS_UTF8 _PyUnicode_AsString
            |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/lib_obj.c:129:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyText_AS_UTF8’
        129 |     char *libname = PyText_AS_UTF8(lib->l_libname);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/lib_obj.c: In function ‘lib_build_and_cache_attr’:
      /opt/conda/envs/cho_env/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:744:29: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        744 | #define _PyUnicode_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
            |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/_cffi_backend.c:71:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyUnicode_AsString’
         71 | # define PyText_AsUTF8 _PyUnicode_AsString   /* PyUnicode_AsUTF8 in Py3.3 */
            |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c/lib_obj.c:208:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyText_AsUTF8’
        208 |     char *s = PyText_AsUTF8(name);
            |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:16,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:6636:
      c/lib_obj.c: In function ‘lib_getattr’:
      c/lib_obj.c:506:7: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        506 |     p = PyText_AsUTF8(name);
            |       ^
      In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:19,
                       from c/_cffi_backend.c:6636:
      c/call_python.c: In function ‘_get_interpstate_dict’:
      c/call_python.c:20:30: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
         20 |     builtins = tstate->interp->builtins;
            |                              ^~
      c/call_python.c: In function ‘_ffi_def_extern_decorator’:
      c/call_python.c:73:11: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
         73 |         s = PyText_AsUTF8(name);
            |           ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
  Running setup.py clean for cffi
Failed to build cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cffi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```

How can I fix or bypass this?
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the same issue. Root cause: the `python-magic` library does not include required binary packages for windows, mac and linux. However, the `python-magic-bin` fork does include them.

Note that `python-libmagic` (which you have tried) would not work for me either. Go for `python-magic-bin` instead.

So, try the following solution (found in this [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1927#issuecomment-425040424)) which worked for me:

```
# uninstall what you initially tried, to avoid conflicts
pip uninstall python-libmagic
pip uninstall python-magic 

# install the working one
pip install python-magic-bin
```

If you are using `conda` (instead of `PyPI`), then you can use `conda install -c conda-forge libmagic`, as per this [GH issue page](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1927#issuecomment-832285613).

Comment: I've removed the libmagic with `pip uninstall libmagic` and installed with `conda install -c conda-forge libmagic` and now seems to be working. Do i really need to add the `python-magic-bin`?

Comment: When i do: `pip install python-magic-bin` i keep getting:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin`

Comment: Re-"Do i really need to add the python-magic-bin?" --> no, this is just one way, which worked for me, but there are several other approaches (like using brew, conda...)

Comment: Re- your second comment, I got no error while installing it with Python 3.11. Pls try adding the specific version that worked for me (currently the latest one): pip install "python-magic-bin==0.4.14"

Comment: I use Python 3.10.12 in this conda env and while installing with specific version i keep  getting:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin==0.4.14 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin==0.4.14` when i search with `conda search -f python-magic` i get only 0.4.13, 0.4.15, 0.4.18, 0.4.22, 0.4.24, 0.4.25, 0.4.27

Comment: looks like 0.4.14 has been only pushed to PyPI by the maintainers. Have you tried with existing versions closer to the 0.4.14 one (say 0.4.15)? I use PyPI and venv for my Python virtual environments, so I have not tested it with conda

Comment: I mean i've installed the `python-magic`  version 0.4.27 however `pip` nor `conda` can find the  package 'python-magic-bin'. It works while only installing the `python-magic` not sure if I need the `python-magic-bin` package at al l?

Comment: Since you are using conda (and not PyPI), I went back to the GH page I referenced in my answer and people there using conda there have solved it by using conda install libmagic instead. (ref: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1927#issuecomment-832285613)

Comment: Yes this works `conda install -c conda-forge libmagic` and `pip uninstall libmagic`

Comment: great, I have edited the answer accordingly, adding the conda approach

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I could use UnstructuredURLLoader by first installing the libmagic dev package for ubuntu and then installing the python interface to libmagic:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev
pip install python-magic
```

Then, I can import the library in Python by:

```py
import magic
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the kernel, execute.
If any module error again change the kernel to the present one.

I solved the issue by changing the kernel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This one is worked for me. There is library version support related issues for UnstructuredURLLoader in libmagic.  You can use SeleniumURLLoader() instead of UnstructuredURLLoader(). For you above code you can modify your code like below:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import SeleniumURLLoader
loader = SeleniumURLLoader(urls=urls)
data = loader.load()
len(data)
```